# Schedule CMS block content change on a specific date

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, date

We have a CMS block on our front page and we would like to automatically change the content of it on Black Friday, for example.

How could we do this?

Comment: does your cms block call a template file? If so could you put some condition in the template that checks date and  displays alternative content?

Comment: Hmm, it doesnt currently, but I guess I could do that, I will play around with that idea, thanks!